# "I have been waiting for you" from Bedazzled

Tags: present-tense

In the movie "Bedazzled" with Brandon Frazer, his character is shown a scene in which he sees the girl he loves and himself. The girl kisses him and says:I have been waiting for you..." If they already met why is there present perfect continuous in that sentence? If present perfect continuous works, would a native speaker use present perfect too?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not clear from your description whether that statement occurs in a scene within a scene in the movie, but it doesn't matter.
The statement
**I have been waiting for you**  is possible either way.
It could mean that the girl who said it had been waiting an hour for him to get back from the store, or it could mean that the girl had been waiting all her life to meet someone **like** him.
A native speaker might say it, but she would probably use the contraction *I've been waiting...*

Comment: Even if the action is obviously no longer in progress. Right?

Comment: Yes. If you have another event to push it further into the past, you could use "I **had**", as in "I had been waiting for you when that picture was taken.", for example.

Comment: Would a native speaker also use present perfect in this sentence?

Comment: Which sentence do you mean, Antonia?

Comment: Past perfect is only used when it's previous to some other mentioned past time. I can say "I have completed that assignment" even if the completion was a month ago. But "I had already completed that assignment before the professor changed the due date."

Comment: @Jack O'Flaherty, I mean present perfect instead of present perfect continuous in "I have been waiting for you". I wanted to ask if past simple could be also used instead of present perfect and present perfect continuous in the original sentence. So "I have waited for you" and "I waited for you." Would they both be possible in the original sentence?

Comment: Yes, they are possible. The sense of "I waited for you." is a little different. It sounds as if the waiting has ended. "I waited 10 years for you, but then I gave up. Now you've come back, but It's too late!" or, "I have waited for you too many times. I'm getting tired of it."

Comment: Thank you for always coming back and answering the questions. I appreciate it. Is the of "I have waited" also different?

Comment: "I have waited" may indicate the waiting has ended. It may also refer to multiple episodes. There's an example in my last comment.